# using java's -XX:OnError option

Tags: java, jvm

I wrote the following code:

```
public class JavaErrorTest {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (1 < 2) {
            throw new OutOfMemoryError();
        }
    }       
}
```

Then I invoke it like:

```
$ java -XX:OnError="echo %p" JavaErrorTest
```

And in my console, I get the following:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
    at JavaErrorTest.main(JavaErrorTest.java:5)
```

Somehow, I suspect that the `-XX:OnError` JVM option is not being picked up. I'm invoking java using cygwin, using jdk 1.6.0_30, running under Windows 64 bits.

What am I doing wrong?

***EDIT***

Following command produces the same output:

```
$ java -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="echo %p" JavaErrorTest
```

Comment: The condition isn't required. ;)

Comment: Can you `touch` a non-existent file at a given location instead of echoing stuff out?

Answer (score 6):

I believe `-XX:OnError` is meant to be used for fatal *virtual machine* errors - i.e. "something is wrong with the JIT, we've generated invalid code" - not "an unhandled exception has been thrown". (Even if this had been thrown by the VM, I wouldn't count this as a VM error.)

Basically I believe it's for debugging the VM, not user code.

EDIT: When using `-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError` I see it *doesn't* use the flag value when you explicitly throw it from user code (which you shouldn't be doing anyway) but *does* use it when you genuinely exhaust memory. For example:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] x = new String[10000000];
        for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            x[i] = new String(new char[10000]);
        }
    }       
}
```

Run with:

```
~ $ java -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="echo %p" Test
#
# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
# -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="echo %p"
#   Executing /bin/sh -c "echo 29712"...
29712
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3057)
    at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:196)
    at Test.main(Test.java:5)
```

(This *still* isn't shown for `OnError` though, which is fair enough - again, it's not showing a bug in the VM.)

Comment: using `-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError` produces the same result

Comment: @chahuistle: Does it produce the same result if you *actually* run out of memory (e.g. by repeatedly using up memory) as opposed to just explicitly throwing `OutOfMemoryError`?

Comment: nope... If a *real* OOE happens, then I get what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, though it doesn't trigger the same error.

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    long[] l = new long[Integer.MAX_VALUE];
}
```

This should trigger the same error.

```
List<byte[]> bytes = new ArrayList<byte[]>();
while (true)
    bytes.add(new byte[64 * 1024 * 1024]);
```

Answer (score 0):

In order for the `-XX:OnError`to be triggered, you will need to use `-XX:+CrashOnOutOfMemoryError` also.