# C++ Program with JNI invoking failed to run in gdb

Tags: java-native-interface, gdb

I wrote a C++ program. It invokes some functions provided by libhdfs(HDFS API for C++, implemented with JNI) and it runs OK when normally executed. When I use gdb to launch the program and input `run` command. The program fails to run and I got the following error message in gdb context:

```
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
[New Thread 0x40100940 (LWP 18482)]
[New Thread 0x40201940 (LWP 18483)]
...
[New Thread 0x41514940 (LWP 18502)]

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00002aaaac26c862 in ?? ()
```

I use command `shell echo $CLASSPATH` in gdb context. It shows the correct HDFS related environment.

I searched with Google and StackOverflow. But I did not get any idea.

Any tip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Why does java app crash in gdb but runs normally in real life?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27241575/why-does-java-app-crash-in-gdb-but-runs-normally-in-real-life) provided a solution:

`handle SIGSEGV nostop noprint pass`

While, it is not so elegant.