# GDB: look at the assembly at certain address?

Tags: debugging, gcc, gdb, gnu, jit

I am working on some JIT compiler and I am using GDB to debut it, my code crashes at some point (segment fault), but it crashes at the jitted code (they are generated on the fly) so I do not get the stack frame information, But I got the following backtrace:

```
#0  0x0000000001d98f22 in ?? () // JITTED CODE
#1  0x000000000000001d in ?? () // JITTED CODE
#2  ...callattribuite function....
```

I am wondering if it is possible for GDB to disassemble the code at location 0x0000000001d98f22 and display it to me. I tried `disas 0x0000000001d98f22` but GDB complained `No function contains specified address.`

---

***EDIT:*** I also fixed this myself, the `disas` command needs a end address to work properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> if it is possible for GDB to disassemble the code at location `0x0000000001d98f22`

Yes: `(gdb) x/20i 0x0000000001d98f22`

If your JIT is done by Java, you should also read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27242060/50617).

Comment: A word of warning though: on a machine with a variable instruction encoding (such as x86 and x86-64) you must pay attention to the offset you start disassembling at, particularly if the break was caused by a SIGILL or similar. Otherwise you may get an incorrect disassembly.