# Debug jni library from clion using gdbserver

Tags: c++, java-native-interface, gdb, clion, gdbserver

I wonder if it's possible to debug jni library from CLION

My setup:

I have remote server with running java application which internaly calls native library.
On the server I started `gdbserver` instance attaching to existing process:

```
gdbserver --attach localhost:7777 pid
```

It successfully connects to the process.

On local machine I create remote debug configuration in CLION specifying 
target remote agrs:

```
tcp:host:7777
```

I also specify symbol file and sysroot.
So when I run this configuration I successfully connect to remote server, but then I keep getting programm pausing because of `SIGPIPE` and `SIGSEGV` signals, so I never get to my real breakpoint. (I believe those are signals inside jvm).

Switching off Exception Breakpoints didn't help.

Is there a way to debug such a setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JVM indeed uses signals under the hood a lot. In order to debug it efficiently you may want to ignore these signals using the `handle` GDB command. Enter it into the GDB console in CLion:

```
(gdb) handle SIGSEGV nostop noprint pass
```

Here's a good [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27242060) to a very close question.