# Segmentation Fault (core dumped) when trying to call a Jar file from within a C program

Tags: java, c, gdb, java-native-interface

I am trying to run a simple C code that calls a Jar file and runs 3 methods from within it. (main, powerMethod, rootMethod) these functions call a C++ shared object. The Jar was already compiled with the .so and runs without errors when used through a Java program.

I am currently getting a `Segmentation fault(core dumped)` error when trying to run the C file. compilation is run without any errors.

compilation line:

```
 gcc -o run java_calls.c -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-16-oracle/include/linux -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-16-oracle/include -L/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-arm64/jre/lib/aarch64/server -ljvm
```

I tried to debug the error and compiled again with the `-g` tag and then ran `gdb run core` and got the following error:

```
Starting program: /home/user/Desktop/JavaFromC/run 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000007fb75072b4 in ?? () from /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-arm64/jre/lib/aarch64/server/libjvm.so
```

C program:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

JNIEnv* create_jvm(JavaVM **java)
{
    JNIEnv *env;
    JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;
    JavaVMOption options;
    int res;

    vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_8;
    vm_args.nOptions = 1;
    vm_args.options = &options;
    vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = 0;
    options.optionString = "-Djava.class.path=./JavaC.jar";
    
    res = JNI_CreateJavaVM(java, (void**)&env, &vm_args);

    if(res < 0 || !env) {
        printf("Failed to create Java VM\n");
    } else {
        printf("JVM Created\n");
    }

    return env;

}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    JavaVM *jvm;
    JNIEnv *env;

    jclass java_c;
    jmethodID main_method;
    jmethodID power_method;
    jmethodID root_method;

    env = create_jvm(&jvm);

    if(env == NULL) {
        exit(1);
    }

    java_cp = (*env)->FindClass(env, "JavaC");
    if(java_cp == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to find JavaC class\n");
        return 1;
    }

    main_method = (*env)->GetStaticMethodID(env, java_c, "main", "([Ljava/lang/String;)V");
    if(main_method == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to find main function\n");
        return 1;
    }

    power_method = (*env)->GetStaticMethodID(env, java_c, "powerMethod", "(I)I");
    if(power_method == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to find power function\n");
        return 1;
    }
    root_method = (*env)->GetStaticMethodID(env, java_c, "rootMethod", "(D)D");
    if(root_method == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to find root function\n");
        return 1;
    }

    jint a_num = 12;
    jdouble b_num = 225;

    (*env)->CallStaticVoidMethod(env, java_c, main_method, NULL);
    printf("power = %d\n", (*env)->CallStaticIntMethod(env, java_c, power_method, a_num));
    printf("root = %f\n", (*env)->CallStaticDoubleMethod(env, java_c, root_method, b_num));

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27242060/50617) may be relevant here. The `SIGSEGV` inside `libjvm.so` is "normal".

What you need to do is continue executing the program (by sending it `SGISEGV` with `signal SIGSEGV` GDB command) and letting it handle the signal, *until* you receive `SIGSEGV` that is *not* coming from `libjvm.so`.

*Then* you would know where the actual fatal `SIGSEGV` is coming from, and why. If you still don't understand the reason for it, you would need to update your question (edit it) with newly-observed info (output from `info locals`, `backtrace`, etc.) and a better answer may be given.